# Interactive installation via Chef

Tags: installation, chef-infra

I am looking to perform a software installation via a Chef cookbook/recipe.  When I run the install command that kicks off the installation, I am taken through a series of questions for which answers must be provided.  How can I make the Chef cookbook/recipe provide answers to these questions as part of installation?

Comment: Are you sure that there are no command line arguments available that allow you to specify these options? About what software are you talking? Is it publicly available?

Comment: The software is not publicly available - it is NetBackup Enterprise Client from Veritas.  I will look into command line options (thank you for pointing me in this direction).  However, my question was to do with what best practices/mechanisms does the Chef community follow in such scenarios (assuming command line options are not possible).

Comment: @nxn Then it's a hard path, installing the program on a clean machine, recording what it does, and replicating what the interactive installer does in a real package system or just dropping files and configurations/registry entries with chef. There's no best way here, it depends on the software

Comment: And with some google search I found [this](https://download.veritas.com/resources/content/live/DOCUMENTATION/6000/DOC6447/en_US/NetBackup76_Install_Guide.pdf?__gda__=1478762397_dcea2236a0c78eaabefe0230ae1b3ca7) documentation with a section named "Installing NetBackup servers silently on Windows
systems". I let you extend from there for your version as you didn't specify it.

Comment: And [this page](https://vox.veritas.com/t5/NetBackup/Netbackup-Client-silent-install/td-p/717310) may be of interest too.

Comment: Thank you, Tensibai.  I will look into the resources you posted.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something Chef handles specifically. You would want to either find instructions on doing an unattended/silent/headless install of the software or write your own script using something like `expect` or `pyexpect` and tell Chef to run that script.